# add a panel or label control dynamically to a datagrid

Tags: datagrid, controls, panel, dynamic

Based on testing values of an existing panel/label inside an ItemTemplate (uses Column1), I want to add another panel/label inside the same ItemTemplate (displays Column2).

This is inside a custom control (.ascx) that I want to control the addition of one particular `<asp:Panel>` based on if  it (or another panel) has a particular value or not. If not, I don't want the `<asp:Panel>` to be created (shouldn't generate the `<div>` at runtime). If yes, I want to generate the `<asp:Panel>` inside 
 the

```
<asp:DataGrid><Columns><ItemTemplate>
```

Example: Assuming we are getting Column2 value as expected, I want to render this value only if it's not '0', if not I don't want to CREATE the extra  tag inside the given `<ItemTemplate>` . I will control when it's rendered based on another tag.

```
If(Column2!='0')
 //Adding some condition for Column1 ... 
  Create the `<div>` tag i.e Add the `<asp:Panel>`
```

How should I call this code also?

That means, the html generated will have the additional div/span tags on some cases and should not have the tags generated on other cases.
Can this be done avoiding Javascript.

Comment: what framework? widget? etc? Where is the question anyhow?

Comment: If this is asp.net, then the answer is yes.  You may want to rephrase and expand on your question with some code to get a more useful answer.

Answer (score 0):

One could use the `<asp:PlaceHolder>` control to place the control at a certain place in the .ascx, say:
`<asp:PlaceHolder id="placeHere" runat="server />` and determine based on the other control whether this should be added.
Example:

```
If(Column1 condition)
 {
  Label addToGrid = new Label();
  addToGrid.Text = column1;
  addToGrid.Visible = true; 
  placeHere.Controls.Add(addToGrid);
}
```